# creating haplotype network plot with MSA package in r

Tags: r

I am trying out the `msa` package and want to create a haplotype network plot. When I ran this command

```
    hap <- haplotype(firstconvert)
    hap
```

I get this warning message:

```
    Warning messages:
1: In haplotype.DNAbin(firstconvert) :
some sequences of different lengths were assigned to the same 
haplotype 
2: In haplotype.DNAbin(firstconvert) :
some sequences were not assigned to the same haplotype because 
of ambiguities
```

and I this that is why my haplotype plot looks so crowded and messy. How can I make my graph look cleaner? I tried messing around with `scale.ratio` and the mutation tick marks to create a nicer looking plot with no luck.

```
plot(net,size=attr(net,"freq"),scale.ratio=4
 ,show.mutation=1,fast=T)
```

[haplotype network plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZ9d.png)

Answer (score 0):

It might help to first align the sequences, using the msa function. For example:

> FirstMSA <- msa(inputSeqs=firstconvert, method=c("CrustalW"), cluster = 'default', gapOpening="default", gapExtension="default", type="default", order=c("aligned"), verbose = FALSE, help= FALSE)

Furthermore, it might also help to build in a threshold in your plot, so that haplotypes that are not very common, aren't shown in your plot (so only the haplotypes that are frequent). For example:

> plot(firstconvert, threshold = c(5,20)) #5 haplotypes is the minimum for showing, 20 is the max.